# How can I show only one Item from same name in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mern

in my  backend data i have list of same name of sectors name like this and it have different of id every item but has the same sector. so I want only  to reduce the same sector name

- **Energy**
- **Energy**
- **Envirnment**
- **Goverment**
- **Envirnment**
- **Aerospace & defence**
- **Aerospace & defence**
- **Manufacturing**
- **Retail**
- **Manufacturing**

but I just want only one name with same value  like this

- **Energy**
- **Envirnment**
- **Goverment**
- **Aerospace & defence**
- **Manufacturing**
- **Retail**

Here is my code

```
const Home = () => {
  const [assignData, setAssignData] = useState([]);

  const datalist = async () => {
    const result = await fetch("http://localhost:5000/api/getalldata");
    const dresult = await result.json();
    setAssignData(dresult);
    
  };
  
  useEffect(() => {
    datalist();
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      {assignData.map((data) => {
        return (
          <>
          <h1> {data.sector} </h1>
         
          </>
        )
      })}
    </>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're only after unique `sector` properties, you can map your `assignData` array to an array of strings and push that through a `Set` to get only unique values.

Here I've used a [memo hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo) to create the `sectors` array and keep it in sync with `assignedData`.

```js
const sectors = useMemo(
  () => [...new Set(assignData.map(({ sector }) => sector))],
  [assignData]
);

return sectors.map((sector) => <h1 key={sector}>{sector}</h1>);
```

Answer (score -1):

You could turn `assignData` into a `Set` and convert it back to an array. This will remove duplicates from the array.

```js
{[... new Set(assignData)].map((data) => {
  return (
    <>
      <h1> {data.sector} </h1>
    </>
  )
})}
```

Comment: it didn't worked show the same result again